# c# selecting distinct rows from datatable

Tags: c#, select, datatable

I know there are a lot of similar questions but they all seem a little different and I can't quite understand the solutions.
I have a datatable `dt2`.  I would like to search on one column and return results based on distinct occurrences of another column. So I am searching for a frequency and I could get multiple rows and this is ok as long as the data in another column is distinct.

```
string spot = "";
string expression = "Freq = '" + frequency + "'"; //search column 4
int count = 0;

DataRow[] results;

results = dt2.Select(expression);

foreach (DataRow row in results)
{
     spot = spot + Convert.ToString(results[count][0]) + " - "; //showing results from column 0
     count = count + 1;
}

spot = spot.Substring(0, spot.Length - 3);
return spot;
```

The `results[count][0]` is the column where I need to be distinct.
Currently in the case where there are 4 frequencies three of which have duplicate column 0's I get this:

> N1ADX - N1ADX - VA2FSQ - N1ADX

But what I want is this:

> N1ADX - VA2FSQ

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this...

```
DataTable results;
dt2.DefaultView.RowFilter = expression;
results = dt2.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "[name_of_column_0]");
foreach (DataRow row in results.rows)
{
    ...
}
```

`View.ToTable` function returns a datatable based on its own data. The first parameter determines if it will contain only different values and the second is a parameter array with the names of the columns you want to include in the datatable.

As stated in another answer, LINQ is also a good option if available.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for the replies. Based on the LINQ I finally ended up with this.  I think the idea of using the foreach loop dir ectly with the datatable was kind of in the way of how to think about this.

```
                    var query = results.Select(x => x.Field<string>("Call")).Distinct();

                    foreach (var callsign in query)
                    {
                        spot = spot + callsign + " - ";
                    }

                    spot = spot.Substring(0, spot.Length - 3);
```

Thanks for all the answers